# Turtle library not working and KTinker library

Tags: python, ubuntu, visual-studio-code, python-turtle

I'm a python beginner and just started out with my first turtle library program, I am using  vscode but it says, "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tkinter'", it gives same error in any online compiler or on ubuntu shell and on vscode as well.
here's the simple code :

```
import turtle as t
w = t.Screen()
turtle_t = t.Turtle()
turtle_t.forward(150)
turtle_t.left(90)
w.exitonclick()
```

Comment: Your code [works fine](https://imgur.com/a/uHjCcgG) on my machine, can you provide detailed error messages so we can reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the package?

Try `pip install tkinter`.